# Accessibility - Alerting users to dynamic text changes inside a button

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I'm trying to improve the accessibility of a button which tests a connection. If the connection is successful, the button text changes to 'Success'. If not, it changes to 'Not Working'. They look something like this:

```
<button aria-label="success">Success!</button>

<button aria-label="failure">Not Working</button>
```

I'm trying to find a way to alert the user of the content change of the button. So far, I've added aria-labels to read the 'success' or 'not working' title, but these are only read to the user if the user tabs/moves away from the button and then back onto it after the status has changed.

I've also tried wrapping the button's text in a `<span>` with a role="alert" in hopes that would notify the user that the text has changed, but no luck there either:

```
<button aria-label="failure"><span role="alert">Not Working</span></button>
```

I've also tried wrapping the button in a `<div aria-live="polite"/>`, but I have suspicion that this isn't working because no new elements are being *added* to the page, but rather the *content* of the elements has changed.

What's a good way to alert users of dynamically changed text content?

Thanks!

Comment: This button fails [WCAG  Success Criterion 2.5.3: Label in Name](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/label-in-name.html) because the visible text ("Not working") is not present in the computed accessible name ("failure").  A speech control user will not be able to operate the button by saying "Click Not Working".  There really isn't much point to the `aria-label` attribute here, it's just going to cause confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close with your attempts.  You **can** have use `aria-live` and is the most appropriate solution.  You don't have to add elements to the DOM for `aria-live` to work.  Changing the text of an element is sufficient if you're using the default `aria-relevant` value.  (If you don't specify `aria-relevant`, you get "additions text" as the default value.)

But you have to put `aria-live` on the element that is changing.  In this case, the button itself.  I tried the following and it worked just fine:

```html
  <button onclick="myclick6()">change it</button>
  <button id='livebutton' aria-live="polite">Success!</button>
```

```js
    function myclick6() {
      document.getElementById("livebutton").innerHTML = "Not Working";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Create simple div with display none.

`<div id="dynamicText" aria-hidden="true" aria-live="assertive" style="display:none"></div>`

After that dynamically append the value inside the above div.

$('#dynamicText').html('Success');
Or
$('#dynamicText').html('Not Working');

Comment: This snippet is unlikely to work, because the use of `display:none` will prevent an aria-live region from being announced.  Was this actually tested with a screen reader?