# How do I get multiple copy buttons with my script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

How can I create several buttons?
I use following script:
"https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2"

Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
```

Here is the button, I want a second worked seperatly below them

```
<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>
```

here I want a second button, but if i use the part below it dont work, it allways copied the first part.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I create several buttons, the top one is always copied. I know that doesn't work.
I want these buttons to act separately from each other. How can I change the code that it will work
If someone would help me, that would be great

I tried a lot but I dont know how coding works.

Comment: Does the second button also have its own input that it's trying to copy? Note: ids on elements must be unique. If you try to use `getElementById('myInput')` for the second button it will always look at the first input.

Comment: How can i do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ids on a page must be unique - so you can either add a new set of an input/button with `myInput2/myButton2` for example, or you could use an alternative method as I've done here.

(Note: rather than having a separate "tooltip" section I would be more inclined to change the text of the button, and then change it back again. This makes the markup a little easier, and accessible. I've made that decision for this example. It doesn't affect the *core* issue of how buttons/inputs can be related to one another which is raised in point 2.)

1. I've removed the inline JS. Buttons are now picked up using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and [the listeners added to them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
2. When a button is clicked it finds its closest [previousElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) which will its sibling input element.
3. When the button is clicked the text is assigned to the clipboard. The button changes text to confirm this, and then after two seconds reverts back to its original text content.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.copy');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});

function handleClick() {

  const input = this.previousElementSibling;
  
  input.select();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(input.value);

  this.textContent = 'Text copied';
  
  setTimeout(() => this.textContent = 'Copy text to clipboard', 2000);

}
```

```css
.copy { width: 10rem; }
```

```html
<section class="field">
  <input type="text" value="Hello World">
  <button class="copy" aria-live="polite">
    Copy text to clipboard
  </button>
</section>
<section class="field">
  <input type="text" value="Hello Planet Earth">
  <button class="copy" aria-live="polite">
    Copy text to clipboard
  </button>
</section>
```

Additional documentation

- Use of [aria-live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746970/accessibility-alerting-users-to-dynamic-text-changes-inside-a-button) when a button changes text content.